# perform fisher test for multiple rows

Tags: r, chi-squared

i have a data called "case.control" has 1000 rows and 2000 col the column are either case or control
so I seprated them based on case and control, so I have now tow data sets
one will be 1000 rows and 400 col = case
another one 1000 rows and 600 col = control
I tried to do fisher test at every rows

```
dat1=c()
dat2=c()
for (i in 1:nrow(case)){
dat1[i]<-table(case[i,])
dat2[i]<-table(control[i,])
tab[i]<-as.table(rbind(dat[i],dat[i]))
fisher.test(tab, alternative="greater")}
```

This code does not work because some times I have zero values in a cell but the code change it to another number for example if I have

```
g1    g2 
400   0
500   100
```

it change it to

```
g1     g2
400   400
500  100
```

any suggestion

the data looks like this sample:

```
Positions      gene1   gene2   gene3 ...... gene2000
 1              0        1       2            2
 2              1        0       0            1
 3              2        1       1            1
 .
 .
 1000           1        0        0           0
```

Comment: Can you provide a small sample data that replicates the problem?

Comment: At the moment your code implies that you have many objects in your workspace: `data.control`, `case`, `control`, and `dat`. You also failed to create the `dat1`, `dat2` or `tab` objects so assignment to "interior values" with `[<-` is likely to fail. I'm guessing that you come from a different programming paradigm where you can easily play around with object names, but such maneuvers are not legal in R. If I'm wrong then you need to provide a small subset of the missing data objects.

Comment: I change the object now. see if you can understand it.

Comment: The structure of the `case` and `control` objects are still unclear. Your example data is just one "thing" but you have two objects. Furthermore this code: `rbind(dat[i],dat[i])` should perhaps be `rbind(dat1[i],dat2[i])` ... or something. Please take the time to post a reproducible example, which unfortunately this is .... not.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major problems with your code.

First, your code will not work because tab, dat1 and dat2 are vectors, and you are treating them as some sort of list or array.

Second, you will also get errors if one row in CASE contains different values than CONTROL.  For example:

```
> x = c(1,2,1,0,1,4,3,2)
> y = c(x, 9)

> rbind(dat1,dat2)
     0 1 2 3 4 9
dat1 1 3 2 1 1 1
dat2 1 3 2 1 1 1
```

Is clearly wrong, since x does not contain a 9 value.  The way to do this is to first convert dat1 and dat2 to factors with specific levels.

Fixed code:

```
dat1=list()
dat2=list()
tab=list()
for (i in 1:nrow(case)){
dat1[[i]]<-table(as.factor(case[i,], levels=1:4) #replace levels with all possible values in your data
dat2[[i]]<-table(as.factor(control[i,], levels=1:4) #replace levels with all possible values in your data
tab[[i]]<-as.table(rbind(dat[i],dat[i]))
fisher.test(tab, alternative="greater")}
```

Comment: it is very good, but there is something wrong                            Error in fisher.test(tab, alternative = "greater") : 
  if 'x' is not a matrix, 'y' must be given